# Netlink interface for arduino - led blink example implementation

Tags: .netlink, guidelines

I'm trying to learn of how I can use netlink in *Mathematica* to communicate with *Arduino*.

So question is the following:

Can some one that has such experience in programming  arduino using `Netlink` in *Mathematica* share a simple example such led blinker so I can understand of how it works?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Mathematica)?

Comment: Yes I did seen that information before, but I don't understand of how to use netlink to communicate with with arduino. I would like to see a simple practical example.

Comment: There's also [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/device/Arduino.html)